# how to filter xml with group wise?

Tags: xslt

This is my xml file

```
<hotels>
    <item>
        <hotelId>1001</hotelId>
        <boardType>Room Only</boardType>
        <rooms>
            <item>
                <roomCategory>Standard Single Room</roomCategory>
                <paxes>
                    <item>
                        <paxType>Adult</paxType>
                        <age>30</age>
                    </item>
                </paxes>
                <totalRoomRate>10</totalRoomRate>
            </item>
            <item>
                <roomCategory>Standard Single Room</roomCategory>
                <paxes>
                    <item>
                        <paxType>Adult</paxType>
                        <age>30</age>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <paxType>Child</paxType>
                        <age>1</age>
                    </item>
                </paxes>
                <totalRoomRate>15</totalRoomRate>
            </item>
            <item>
                <roomCategory>Standard Single Room</roomCategory>
                <paxes>
                    <item>
                        <paxType>Adult</paxType>
                        <age>30</age>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <paxType>Child</paxType>
                        <age>14</age>
                    </item>
                </paxes>
                <totalRoomRate>20</totalRoomRate>
            </item>
            <item>
                <roomCategory>Standard Single Room</roomCategory>
                <paxes>
                    <item>
                        <paxType>Adult</paxType>
                        <age>30</age>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <paxType>Adult</paxType>
                        <age>30</age>
                    </item>
                </paxes>
                <totalRoomRate>20</totalRoomRate>
            </item>
            <item>
                <roomCategory>Standard Single Room</roomCategory>
                <paxes>
                    <item>
                        <paxType>Adult</paxType>
                        <age>30</age>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <paxType>Child</paxType>
                        <age>14</age>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <paxType>Child</paxType>
                        <age>10</age>
                    </item>
                </paxes>
                <totalRoomRate>25</totalRoomRate>
            </item>
            <item>
                <roomCategory>Standard Single Room</roomCategory>
                <paxes>
                    <item>
                        <paxType>Adult</paxType>
                        <age>30</age>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <paxType>Child</paxType>
                        <age>14</age>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <paxType>Child</paxType>
                        <age>10</age>
                    </item>
                </paxes>
                <totalRoomRate>20</totalRoomRate>
            </item>
            <item>
                <roomCategory>Standard Single Room</roomCategory>
                <paxes>
                    <item>
                        <paxType>Adult</paxType>
                        <age>30</age>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <paxType>Adult</paxType>
                        <age>30</age>
                    </item>
                </paxes>
                <totalRoomRate>20</totalRoomRate>
            </item>
        </rooms>
    </item>
    <item>
        <hotelId>1002</hotelId>
        <boardType>Room Only</boardType>
        <rooms>
            <item>
                <roomCategory>Double/twin Deluxe</roomCategory>
                <paxes>
                    <item>
                        <paxType>Adult</paxType>
                        <age>30</age>
                    </item>
                </paxes>
                <totalRoomRate>10</totalRoomRate>
            </item>
            <item>
                <roomCategory>Double/twin Deluxe</roomCategory>
                <paxes>
                    <item>
                        <paxType>Adult</paxType>
                        <age>30</age>
                    </item>
                </paxes>
                <totalRoomRate>12</totalRoomRate>
            </item>
        </rooms>
    </item>
    <item>
        <hotelId>1003</hotelId>
        <boardType>Bed And Breakfast</boardType>
        <rooms>
            <item>
                <roomCategory>Double/twin Deluxe</roomCategory>
                <paxes>
                    <item>
                        <paxType>Adult</paxType>
                        <age>30</age>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <paxType>Child</paxType>
                        <age>3</age>
                    </item>
                </paxes>
                <totalRoomRate>20</totalRoomRate>
            </item>
        </rooms>
    </item>
</hotels>
```

XML output i showing below

---

```
Hotel ID: 1001

Room Type              Board Type    Quantity  Adults   Child    Price
Standard Single Room   Room Only     1           1          0      10
Standard Single Room   Room Only     1           1          1      15
Standard Single Room   Room Only     1           1          1      20
Standard Single Room   Room Only     1           2          0      20
Standard Single Room   Room Only     1           1          2      25
Standard Single Room   Room Only     1           1          2      20
Standard Single Room   Room Only     1           2          0      20


Hotel ID: 1002

Room Type              Board Type    Quantity   Adults  Child     Price
Double/twin Deluxe     Room Only     1           1        0        10
Double/twin Deluxe     Room Only     1           1        0        12

Hotel ID: 1003

Room Type              Board Type    Quantity   Adults  Child     Price
Double/twin Deluxe     Bed And Breakfast  1      1        1        20
```

---

But i need to filter the above results with xsl like below

---

```
Hotel ID: 1001

Room Type              Board Type     Quantity   Adults   Child    Price
Standard Single Room   Room Only         1         1        0       10
Standard Single Room   Room Only         2         1        1       35
Standard Single Room   Room Only         2         2        0       40
Standard Single Room   Room Only         2         1        2       45

Hotel ID: 1002

Room Type              Board Type     Quantity   Adults   Child    Price
Double/twin Deluxe     Room Only         2         1        0       22

Hotel ID: 1003

Room Type              Board Type     Quantity   Adults   Child    Price
Double/twin Deluxe     Bed And Breakfast 1         1        1       20
```

---

1. if you take total quantity it should be on same "Room Type", "Board Type", "Adults" and "Child"
2. if you take total Price it should be the  total of that group

How i do this in xsl file

hoping your help

Comment: Are you using XSLT1.0 or 2.0? This is a grouping problem, and XSLT2.0 has dedicated grouping commands, whereas in XSLT1.0 you would need to use a technique called "Meunchian Grouping".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this in XSLT1.0, you will need to use a technique called Meunchian Grouping.

In your case you are gouping by Hotel ID, Board Type, Category, Adult and Children, which means defined quite a complicated key

```
<xsl:key 
   name="items" 
   match="rooms/item" 
   use="concat(../../hotelId, 
      '|', ../../boardType, 
      '|', roomCategory, 
      '|', count(paxes/item[paxType='Adult']), 
      '|', count(paxes/item[paxType='Child']))" />
```

Do note use of the 'pipe' character to separate the various fields in the key. It is important this character does not actually occur in any of the fields itself.

Next (for a given hotel id), you start off by finding the first element in each group, like so:

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="rooms/item[generate-id() 
      = generate-id(key('items', 
         concat(../../hotelId, 
         '|', ../../boardType, 
         '|', roomCategory, 
         '|', count(paxes/item[paxType='Adult']), 
         '|', count(paxes/item[paxType='Child'])))[1])]" 
  mode="group"/>
```

Then, once you have matched the first element in a group, you can then loop through all the elements in the group, or in your case, aggregate them together

So, given the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="items" match="rooms/item" use="concat(../../hotelId, '|', ../../boardType, '|', roomCategory, '|', count(paxes/item[paxType='Adult']), '|', count(paxes/item[paxType='Child']))"/>

   <xsl:template match="/hotels">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="hotels/item">
      <h1>
         <xsl:value-of select="concat('Hotel ID: ', hotelId)"/>
      </h1>
      <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Room Type</th>
               <th>Board Type</th>
               <th>Quantity</th>
               <th>Adults</th>
               <th>Child</th>
               <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="rooms/item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('items', concat(../../hotelId, '|', ../../boardType, '|', roomCategory, '|', count(paxes/item[paxType='Adult']), '|', count(paxes/item[paxType='Child'])))[1])]" mode="group"/>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="rooms/item" mode="group">
      <xsl:variable name="groupitems" select="key('items', concat(../../hotelId, '|', ../../boardType, '|', roomCategory, '|', count(paxes/item[paxType='Adult']), '|', count(paxes/item[paxType='Child'])))"/>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="roomCategory"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../boardType"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="count($groupitems)"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(paxes/item[paxType='Adult'])"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(paxes/item[paxType='Child'])"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum($groupitems/totalRoomRate)"/>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output:

```
<h1>Hotel ID: 1001</h1>
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Room Type</th>
         <th>Board Type</th>
         <th>Quantity</th>
         <th>Adults</th>
         <th>Child</th>
         <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Standard Single Room</td>
         <td>Room Only</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td>10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Standard Single Room</td>
         <td>Room Only</td>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>35</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Standard Single Room</td>
         <td>Room Only</td>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td>40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Standard Single Room</td>
         <td>Room Only</td>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>45</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<h1>Hotel ID: 1002</h1>
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Room Type</th>
         <th>Board Type</th>
         <th>Quantity</th>
         <th>Adults</th>
         <th>Child</th>
         <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Double/twin Deluxe</td>
         <td>Room Only</td>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td>22</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<h1>Hotel ID: 1003</h1>
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Room Type</th>
         <th>Board Type</th>
         <th>Quantity</th>
         <th>Adults</th>
         <th>Child</th>
         <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Double/twin Deluxe</td>
         <td>Bed And Breakfast</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>20</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

solution in XSLT 2.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="hotels/item">
        <h1>Hotel ID: <xsl:value-of select="hotelId"/></h1>
        <br/>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Room Type</th>
                    <th>Board Type</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Adults</th>
                    <th>Child</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:variable name="BT" select="boardType"/>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="rooms/item" group-by="count(paxes/item[paxType='Adult']) * 1000 + count(paxes/item[paxType='Child'])">
                    <xsl:for-each select=".">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="roomCategory"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="$BT"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="count(./paxes/item[paxType='Adult'])"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="count(./paxes/item[paxType='Child'])"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/totalRoomRate)"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which gives as result

```
<h1>Hotel ID: 1001</h1><br><table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Room Type</th>
            <th>Board Type</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Adults</th>
            <th>Child</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Standard Single Room</td>
            <td>Room Only</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Standard Single Room</td>
            <td>Room Only</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>35</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Standard Single Room</td>
            <td>Room Only</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>40</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Standard Single Room</td>
            <td>Room Only</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>45</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<h1>Hotel ID: 1002</h1><br><table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Room Type</th>
            <th>Board Type</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Adults</th>
            <th>Child</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Double/twin Deluxe</td>
            <td>Room Only</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>22</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<h1>Hotel ID: 1003</h1><br><table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Room Type</th>
            <th>Board Type</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Adults</th>
            <th>Child</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Double/twin Deluxe</td>
            <td>Bed And Breakfast</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks, but i getting error
msxml3.dll error '80004005'

Keyword xsl:for-each may not contain xsl:for-each-group.

Comment: what xslt processor are you using? I don't get that error in XML Spy. I will retry in saxon 9 home edition. Looks like it's a microsoft vba dll?

Comment: i am new in xsl. i run code in my asp page using "xml.transformNode(xsl)"

Comment: Tried in saxon9he.jar - no problem. Good old Microsoft hindering us again :-)  Tried running it in vba msxml2 and got similar error: "Keyword tbody may not contain xsl:for-each-group". Running in MS apparently requires different xslt setup, one template calling another probably.

Comment: Actually my guess is that msxml3.dll does not support XSLT 2.0 or maybe not fully (no grouping). Try using a different dll that does support XSLT 2.0 fully.

Comment: Checked MS site and found a remark confirming this: "question: Will MSXML support XSLT 2.0? answer: No. MSXML versions 6.0 fully implement and support XSL Transformations (XSLT) Version 1.0 (W3C Recommendation 16 November 1999)." So I will   leave the stage for XSLT 1.0 Muenchian Grouping experts now :-).

Comment: thanks mr.maestro... i d't have option to check 2.0. but i hope that your solution is currect